# Are there any special characters that are never allowed in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, mysql, oracle, java

I am a Java programmer. We always make database-related things configurable so that they can be easily modified by the DB team as per their requirements.

I want to make some queries as configurable, the problem is I am not able to find a separator for separating queries.

I will later use this separator in the program to separately execute these queries.

Can anyone tell me any separator or a special symbol that is never used in SQL?

**Note:** As of now I am using comma (,) as the separator but this has a high possibility that my program may fail in future if any query contains comma (,) in it.

Answer (score 2):

The statement terminator in SQL Server is a semi-colon `;`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177563.aspx

As queries cannot contain a semi-colon, except as the last character to identify the end of the query, this should be enough for you to separate out each statement.

Comment: that's not entirely true. a `create procedure` can contain a `;` which doesn't terminate the statement. But as mateen talks about "queries" I guess that isn't an issue here. Of course he/she needs to check for quoted values `select ';' from foo;`

Comment: consider the following
a column value which consists lists of queries and this value include almost every common symbol like semicolon,comma,period etc. so here we used @#$% as the separator, then it is not a good thing to do

I need a more generic way to make queries configurable.

Comment: If it's a column value, then it must be within quotation marks ';'. Do your Java coding better...

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating comma delimited files, you should probably use double quote and comma delimited. Excel can read the files as is, and you are less likely to have the data in the database mess up the format. I have also used the tilde ~ as a delimiter. It doesn't get used very often so it tends to be safe to use.

Comment: we have grid queries configured and these queries are like heavy weight nested queries. so, believe me the queries are so messed up there are queries whose character length is even greater than 1000 characters.